# How do i calculate average times in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, momentjs

I have an object which has the following entry in it:

```
   numberOfReturns: number = 0;
   returns_explanations: string [] = [];
   departure_time: string = '';
   arrival_time: string = '';
```

So in departure_time i have the following information:

```
...
departure_time: 08:15
departure_time: 08:02
departure_time: 09:00
...
```

I have an array of this whole object which will need to be iterated and i need to get the average departure_times.

```
let average: Date = null;

for (let i = 0; i < workAccountItem.length; i++) {
    average = moment(average).add(moment('01/01/2021 ' + workAccountItem[i].departure_time));
}

average = average / workAccountItem.length;
```

This approach won't work.

Comment: Get hours and minutes from `moment`'s particular dates and calculate an average then..

Answer (score 0):

In your main type interface, it looks like you have an extra space between `string` and `[]` for `returns_explanations` -- if you're defining a prop as having a type array of strings, it should be `string[]` with no space. For your type definition for `average`, you can also set it to being either `Date` or `null` like so, `average: Date | null`, which will prevent type errors when no date is present yet.